# Why is Firefox for Android shown as "offered by" Google Commerce Ltd?

Tags: google-play-store

If you look at the page for Firefox for Android on Google Play, and it 'Read more' then scroll all the way down, you will see the following. The question is simple, why is it shows an offered by Google and not Mozilla?

[image: IMG:]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think it's necessarily a glitch. Legally, the offering source depends on your country. For example, [in the UK](https://play.google.com/intl/en_gb/about/play-terms/),

> Content on Google Play is offered by Google Commerce Limited, located at Gordon House, Barrow Street, Dublin 4, Ireland. Such Content may originate from another source (such as an app developer, book publisher, movie studio, or music label) (the “Provider” of the Content).

However, [in the US](https://play.google.com/intl/en_us/about/play-terms/):

> Content may be offered by Google or made available by third-parties not affiliated with Google. Google is not responsible for and does not endorse any Content made available through Google Play that originates from a source other than Google.

I guess this is just to comply with legal requirements in certain jurisdictions.

Comment: This looks correct. FWIW, here's the link to Firefox on Play Store, [geolocked to the UK](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.mozilla.firefox&gl=GB) and [geolocked to the US](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.mozilla.firefox&gl=US).